# When to use variable/reference parameters as an output?

Tags: c++, variables, parameters, reference, output

Should I use parameters to a function as the output? If so, when? 
I've seen some WinAPI functions do this, and I don't understand what the reasoning is.

```
    LARGE_INTEGER c;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&c);
    ...
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&c);
```

Why is a reference used when the code below, seemingly, would do the same? (assuming the function simply returned the result)

```
    LARGE_INTEGER c = QueryPerformanceCounter();
    ...
    c = QueryPerformanceCounter();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this is because of an (outdated) concern about the efficiency of returning larger objects by value, but in this case I think the reason was to allow the return value to be used as a status indicating whether the call succeeded or not.

Comment: So it's due to efficiency? I have a function that returns an array with lengths over 2 million (pure image data). Will using a reference rather than return value be beneficial?

Comment: @John: In some cases, passing an object to the function can let you reuse storage, which can cut down on allocation and deallocation times. When it comes to performance, it is best to measure though. There are few hard-and-fast rules.

Answer (score 1):

It can be very useful if you want to return an error from the function in order to validate the output:

```
std::string input;

if(!read_device(input))
{
    log("ERROR: reading device:");
    return false;
}

// input is valid here
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the explanation for Win32 functions.  They follow a convention where the return value indicates success or failure (with very few exceptions)